# How to prepare input file for svmstruct

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm, named-entity-recognition, svmlight

I want to use svmstruct for my Named entity Recognition task. Some of my features for each token are not in numerical format ( mostly in textual format such a n-char affixes or word shape ,...) . Since svmstruct's input format is same as svmlight format , I would like to know how should i convert those textual features to numerical ones?

All Bests

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to encode your text data as binary categories.

For example lets say you have the data

> ```
> affix    shape
> ==============
> ing      lower
>          initcap
> ed       allcaps
> ```

What you want to send to svmstruct is something like this:

> ```
> affix_ing:1 shape_lower:1
> shape_initcap:1
> affix_ed:1 shape_allcaps
> ```

Now you can't you words as column identifiers, but svmstruct uses a sparse format so you can use widely separate column numbers as long as they are unique.

This is a great application for a hash function.  So the technique is to make up column IDs on the fly and dummy encode your discrete data.

> ```
> hash(colName + colValue) => 1
> ```

Depending on your data you might not need colName. Is a colName likely to collide with a colValue?

You can use a hash function like murmur hash or cityhash to get a huge space with fast calculation and low collisions.